# Why can I not pass an ifstream as I construct it?

Tags: c++, ifstream

The compiler does not like the the main program below

```
int get1(ifstream &f){
  int count;
  f >> count;
return count;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  cout << get1(ifstream(argv[1])) << endl;
}
```

The error message is:

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
test.cpp:11:33: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 's\
td::ifstream& {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>&}' from an rvalue of type 'std::if\
stream {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>}'
test.cpp:4:5: error: in passing argument 1 of 'int get1(std::ifstream&)'
```

This does work if the main program is written as

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
  ifstream f(argv[1]);
  cout << get1(f) << endl;
}
```

Is there a way to make the compact first form work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
get1(ifstream(argv[1]))
```

You are constructing a **temporary** `ifstream` object. Temporary objects can only be bound to const references (`const ifstream&`), not to non-const references (`ifstream&`).

> Is there a way to make the compact first form work?

It depends on which version of C++ you're using.

**In C++11** you can change your function to use a *rvalue* reference instead of a *lvalue* reference: `int get1(ifstream&& f)`. Then it will gladly accept temporary objects. (*solution courtesy of @soon*)

Note however that with this solution, if you want to use the less compact form `ifstream f(argv[1]); get1(f);` the compiler won't accept it as is (`cannot bind ‘T’ lvalue to ‘T&&’`). You'll have to use `std::move` in order to convert the *lvalue* to a *rvalue*: `get1(std::move(f));`.

Another way, which avoids the `std::move` requirement, would be to use a template function with an *universal reference* (special case of *rvalue* references for templates, that allows the *rvalue* reference to decay to a *lvalue* reference): `template<Stream> int get1(Stream&& f)` (*courtesy @soon once again*)

**In C++03** there is no standard way to do it: since temporary objects can only be bound to const references, you'd have to change your function to `int get1(const ifstream& f)` which would render your `ifstream` useless (who'd want an `ifstream` that can't be read because it is `const`?).

Comment: Though I'm very reluctant to mention it, because it absolutely sucks, there is a way: MSVC's evil extension.

Comment: @chris Yes I hesitated to mention it, but finally decided against: call me pedantic but this is not C++ any more.

Comment: I'm not sure, but isn't passing by r-reference a solution?

Comment: @soon: ah right, I didn't think about that. Takes time to ramp up the reflexes to C++11, I'm a slow learner. Thanks, I'll update my answer. :)

Comment: Thanks!  If I make the get1 parameter ifstream&& the call get1(argv[1]) does indeed work.  However, now get1(f) where f is a lvalue does not work!  It appears that this also as per C++11.  In any case thanks much.

Comment: @Ekalavya: I guess you didn't see my latest edit where I address this issue. ;) In short: `get1(std::move(f));`

Comment: @syam, Or use universal reference.(`template <class Srteam> int get1(Stream&& s) { ... }`)